# How do you recharge the venom edge?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

Is it possible to recharge the venom edge (or other similar magical weapons)?

If it is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Once you consume all the charges of a charged item, the magical energy is gone for good. You might still want to hold onto the base item if it's useful. For example,

> the Flame Blade in the Halls of Fire on Level 6

is a perfectly good Longsword once its charges are depleted.

I've found a couple of items in Grimrock that are permanently "charged" with some kind of magical/elemental energy, but they're usually very challenging to get, and they can't release a spell on command. For instance,

> the Dismantler sword in the Vault occasionally deals shock damage

when you wield it. I haven't found any items that are both permanently charged *and* can release energy on command like the limited-charge items do.

Answer (score 0):

recharging crystals can be found to reload the item charges

Comment: Can you provide more details? What do recharging crystals look like? Where do they tend to be found?

Comment: I think he is referring to the _Crystal Shard of Recharging_ (Legend of Grimrock 2). [Here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/DFIRZ7R).